# Monitoring (summarizing) network usage of a single application (process) (Linux)

Tags: networking, performance-monitoring, bandwidth-measuring

I have a single application that seems to be a network pig (based on a casual glance at its logs - it seems awfully chatty).  I'd like to find out what its bandwidth usage is - preferably in the form of a summary timeline, e.g., incoming/outgoing total bytes every minute (alternatively, in a form I can summarize that way myself with other tools).

If it is something that can be done with standard tools like iftop, netstat, etc., I don't know how to arrange that, so instructions (or pointer to instructions) would be appreciated.

Linux (not Ubuntu).

Comment: Not Ubuntu? Should we guess which distribution it is? It might not matter, but there are often surprising and subtle differences.

Comment: Raspian.  But I guess it doesn't much matter, really, you're right.